# Cutting down a very large table into something importable

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a .dbf file that is over 4 GB in size, which is too large for the MS Access 2003 2 GB limit. However, the relevant cut of data I need is < 2GB, which is usable in Access.

Lexicographically speaking, I want to make/import all rows for which the string field FIELD is ">D2*" which means anything from "D3..." onward.

Can this be done? (I also have Access 2007 to use)

Comment: First thing I would try is to see if the provider of the data will cut it down for you.

Answer (score 1):

If your file doesn't have more than 65,536 records, you may want to open the file in [Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx), and export to the appropriate .mdb or .accdb file.

Or, are you asking for a specific query to identify the rows in your existing DB program?

Comment: It's over 4 GB, it has millions of rows well over what would open up nicely in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-time import into Access, or do you need to do this multiple times?
If it is a one time thing, I'd use a DBF filtering tool, then export it:

[DBF Tools](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-tools.html)

[DBF Viewer 2000](http://www.dbf2002.com/help/filtering_records_in_dbf.htm)

Comment: It is a daily process I wish to automate in the morning. Right now I run a batch process from the Windows Scheduler that does some really gross text converting but it's wicked slow and highly prone to delimiter errors.

EDIT: DBF Viewer is actually what I use to do the splitting.

Comment: How about in Access, on the "External Data" tab, using ODBC as a source. You can set up an ODBC source pointing to your dbase file, but using a query for the WHERE exclusions you want to try.

Comment: I tried but now it's asking for a driver or something and I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: External Data tab, ODBC Database, import the source data, and now I have a File Data Source and Machine Data Source tab and I'm not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

> Lexicographically speaking, I want to make/import all rows for which
>   the string field FIELD is ">D2*" which means anything from "D3..."
>   onward.

Yes, you can do that. Ideally, you'd just attach that table (File | Get external data | Link tables, I think, in older versions of Access), and select from it. If you can't do that, you'll need to export the result of

```
select *
from your_table
where your_column > 'D2';
```

Then import that into Access.

You might be able to export into a format that Access *will* attach. If you can do that, your life gets simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, and what I did was:

- Set up dbf2csv script (https://gist.github.com/bertspaan/8220892)
- use that to convert the DBF file to a CSV
- Use standard Linux commands(head, tail,...) to slice up the .CSV as needed